# How to extract shortcode from shortcode with this format:

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

If you have a shortcode that is created like this:

```
[shortcode1 attribute1="content" attribute2="content with [shortcode2] too"]
```

because shortcode2 is being used this way, it is breaking shortcode1. How do I extract the attribute2 content and then execute the shortcode2?

Currently I am extracting the attributes like this:

`extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'attribute1' => '',
'attribute2' => ''), $atts ) );`
But having shortcode2 in an attribute breaks the output completely.

Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `do_shortcode()`  for the content of `attribute2` when returning from first shortcode function call

Like `do_shortcode($atts['attribute2']);`

### [**How to Create Nested Shortcodes in WordPress**](http://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-nested-shortcodes/)

Comment: Thanks for that, but where do I apply that? Because If I do a var_dump of the attribute using your exact syntax after the attributes have been extracted, it isn't working, it only outputs the "content with" part, but ignores the shortcode2 + the following content ("too")

Comment: I think it's because the second shortcode has brackets that are breaking the first ones, is there any truth in that?

Comment: @user2413333 have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes